# Using StreamReader split methode to create a txt file from a CSV file

Tags: c#, streamreader

I want to extract each string between the first "" for each row and create a text file with it.

sample CSV:

```
number,season,episode,airdate,title,tvmaze link
1,1,1,13 Sep 05,"Pilot","https://www.tvmaze.com/episodes/991/supernatural-1x01-pilot"
2,1,2,20 Sep 05,"Wendigo","https://www.tvmaze.com/episodes/992/supernatural-1x02-wendigo"
3,1,3,27 Sep 05,"Dead in the Water","https://www.tvmaze.com/episodes/993/supernatural-1x03-dead-in-the-water"
4,1,4,04 Oct 05,"Phantom Traveler","https://www.tvmaze.com/episodes/994/supernatural-1x04-phantom-traveler"
5,1,5,11 Oct 05,"Bloody Mary","https://www.tvmaze.com/episodes/995/supernatural-1x05-bloody-mary"
```

Final result .txt file:

```
Pilot
Wendigo
Dead in the Water
Phantom Traveler
Bloody Mary
```

my function:

```
private void GetEpisodeNamesFromCSV()
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(AppDir + "\\list.csv"))
    {
        string strResult = sr.ReadToEnd();
        string[] result = strResult.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        File.WriteAllLines(AppDir + "\\list_generated_" + ShowTitel + ".txt", result);
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to properly Split the stream reader object, to only get the names on each Line. I'm very new to programming, and this site helped me immensely! But this problem is specific, and I couldn't find the answer myself. I appreciate any help.

EDIT:

I went with the csvHelper solution suggested by @Jesús López:

```
// Create a List
List<string> episodeNames = new List<string>();

// Make sure ther are no empty lines in the csv file
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(AppDir + "\\list.csv").Where(arg => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(arg));
File.WriteAllLines(AppDir + "\\list.csv", lines);

// Open the file stream
var streamReader = File.OpenText(AppDir + "\\list.csv");
var csv = new CsvReader(streamReader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// Read the File
csv.Read();

// Read the Header
csv.ReadHeader();

// Create a string array with Header
string[] header = csv.Context.Reader.HeaderRecord;

// Select the column and get the Index
var columnExtracted = "title";
int extractedIndex = Array.IndexOf(header, columnExtracted);

// Read the file and fill the List
while (csv.Read())
{
    string[] row = csv.Context.Reader.Parser.Record;
    string column = row[extractedIndex];
    episodeNames.Add(column);
}

// Convert the List to a string array
string[] result = episodeNames.ToArray();

//write the array to a text file
File.WriteAllLines(AppDir + "\\list.txt", result);
```

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel again and use a proper CSV parser like https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper

Comment: Create a class with header information, inside loop, split by comma and assing values to the instance of class that you created add that instance to a list and finally you can select episodes with using linq.

Answer (score 0):

This is not so much help on StreamReader as it is on strings
If you are confident of the file layout and format as shown (and that it will be consistent), try this quick-and-dirty in a Console app

```
:
var line = sr.ReadLine();
while (line != null)
{
  if (line.Trim() == string.Empty) continue;
  var lineEntries = line.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
  Console.WriteLine(lineEntries[4].Trim('"'));
  line = sr.ReadLine();
}
```

Note that I offer this because of your statement "I am very new to programming" to show off methods `string.Split()` `.Trim()` (and check out `.Join()`) and how easy they make the basic logic of what you want to achieve.

Using a proper CSV reader is the best idea for a robust solution (plus data-integrity checking, exception handling etc), but there is a reciprocal danger of over-engineering, so if this code displays what you want/expect for a once-off learning experience, then go ahead and implement;-)

Comment: thank you very much, I will try this one out for better understanding.